# Android, How to restart/refresh a fragment from FragmentActivty?

Tags: android, fragment

In my FragmentActivity I have a fragment. This fragment loads data from server.
I want we user clicks on refresh button then I call a method in fragment and do refreshing process.

I created an interface in FragmentActivity and set its variable when user clicks on refresh button. The code is like this:

```
public class MainScreen extends FragmentActivity {
    public interface OnRefreshSelected {
        public void refreshFragment(boolean flag);
    }

    private OnRefreshSelected onRefreshSelected;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Log.i(TAG, "Try to create MainScreen...");

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        onRefreshSelected = (OnRefreshSelected) MainScreen.this;
    }

     @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_refresh:
                        onRefreshSelected.refreshFragment(true);
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And in Fragment class i implemented this interface:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements OnRefreshSelected {
    @Override
    public void refreshFragment(boolean flag) {
        Log.i(TAG, "refresh requested. Try to reload data for this fragment...");

        getData();
    }
}
```

When I run, the application crashes and logcat shows this message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.astro.recipe.activities/com.astro.recipe.activities.MainScreen}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.astro.recipe.activities.MainScreen
```

and points to this line:

```
onRefreshSelected = (OnRefreshSelected) MainScreen.this;
```

What is the best way to have access to a method of fragment from its host?
any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can I use your code with AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing this

```
onRefreshSelected = (OnRefreshSelected) MainScreen.this;
```

you are assigning your activity in `onRefreshSelected` field, trying to cast it to your interface, but your activity doesn't implement the interface, that's why `ClassCastException` raised.

Instead use something like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_refresh:
                    CategoryFragment fragment = (CategoryFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.category_fragment);
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        fragment.getData();
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Your activity can call methods in the fragment by acquiring a reference to the Fragment from FragmentManager, using [findFragmentById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29) or [findFragmentByTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer using Interfaces. Therefore, I replaced onRefreshSelected = (OnRefreshSelected) MainScreen.this;  by onRefreshSelected = new TopRecipesFragment(); and onRefreshSelected = new CategoryFragment(); Now it works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Answer (score -1):

I agree with biegleux... But my suggestion is

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment{

   private static CategoryFragment categoryFrag;

    private CategoryFragment(){}

    public static CategoryFragment getInstance(){
        if(null == categoryFrag){
            categoryFrag = new CategoryFragment();
        }

        return categoryFrag;
    }

    public void  getData(){
       /*** Screen Refresh code****/
    }
}
```

I your active when he selects option

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_refresh:
                    CategoryFragment fragment = CategoryFragment.getInstance();
                     fragment.getData();

                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```