# Fragment Management?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am Using android Library_JakeWharton_ActionBarSherlock for implementing facebook, linked-in and other application like sliding bar,

Facing a problem going to back from i.e. Fragment B - > Fragment A.

I have a fragment called Result and another one is Details, when user click on particular item in Result Detail Fragment will called.

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    if (getActivity() instanceof FragmentInitializer) {
        FragmentInitializer fca = (FragmentInitializer) getActivity();
        fca.switchContent(fragment);
    }
}
```

used this method for navigate from one fragment to another fragment.

How can I back from Details Fragment to Result Fragment.
Below is my Result Fragments class

```
public class Result_Fragments extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout lnr_main = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_layout, null);
        getInit(lnr_main);
        return lnr_main;
    }
}
```

I have tried below code.

1) getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
2) android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

```
            if(mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStack();
            }
```

Comment: This question has your answer
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918198/how-to-keep-tabs-visible-on-every-activity

Comment: @Raj, I have no tabbar fragment, I have slidebar fragment, I have implemented  JakeWharton / ActionBarSherlock lib. for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code when you launch detail fragment from result fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.left_framelayout, DetailFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```