# Pass message from Activity to a programatically created Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Good day, you awesome people! Here's my case. I want to refresh the contents of a nested fragment based on an option from the ActionBar. The fragment has a ListView and should display one list if the first ActionBar option is selected and another list if the second option is selected. Let's say I have couple of options in my ActionBar (**"All"** and **"Highlighted"**).

[image]

The desired fragment is in a TabHost, which has a ViewPager.

```
<TabHost>

<LinearLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In addition, this is how I add a tab:

```
mHomeTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("controls").setIndicator("CONTROLS"), ControlsFragment.class, null);
```

Since I'm adding the fragment programatically, I cannot give it an id and use the FragmentManager to find it by ID. How do I get a reference to ControlsFragment so I can refresh it from MainActivity's onNavigationItemSelected?

In the ideal situation, I should be able to get a reference to the fragment within onNavigationItemSelected and reinstantiate the adapter that provides the list with items.

I read the communication article (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) but I'm afraid it's not going to work for me. Anyone got suggestions?

Comment: check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918198/how-to-keep-tabs-visible-on-every-activity/17918804#17918804

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Use a tag!

When you do a transaction you can specify a tag.

```
 FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment fragment, String tag);
```

You can find the fragment with

```
 FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tag);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not doing transactions. I'm using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to sync and feed items to the TabHost and ViewPager. Internally, the adapter gives me the proper fragment in the following manner: 
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);

        return fragment;
    }