# refresh a fragment from its parent activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have almost the exact same problem as this question here: [Android, How to restart/refresh a fragment from FragmentActivty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578000/android-how-to-restart-refresh-a-fragment-from-fragmentactivty)

I'm trying to call the a method of a `ListFragment` from the parent `FragmentActivity`.

However, I'm using the template Swipe + Fixed Tabs generated by eclipse. I tried calling `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myfragment)` but the return value is always null. I'm guessing this might be a problem because I did not define `myfragment` anywhere in my app. But I am unsure where to define it as all fragments are created dynamically.

For those who are not familiar with the Swipe + Fixed Tabs template generated by the Android SDK in Eclipse, the fragments are created by overriding the `FragmentPagerAdapter` `getItem` function, returning a new instance of my fragment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant code:
How I setup my adapter:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_comment);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Overriding the adapter getItem function:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return CommentsFragment.newInstance();

        case 1:
        default:
            return LikesFragment.newInstance();
        }
    }
```

The newInstance() functions simply return an instance of themselves, since the classes for my fragment are static.

Comment: you should post relevant snippet of code. All the same, if I have not misunderstood your issue, you can try to assign a tag to the fragment a try to retrieve it with findFragemtByTag

Comment: Updated question with relevant code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find your fragment by the Tag, but of course you need to give this tag to it while adding the fragment.

First add your fragment with a tag:

```
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        SomeFragment fragment = new ManageLinksFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container1,fragment, "sometag");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And then on the Activity's site:

```
SomeFragment mSomeFragment = (SomeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("sometag");
// now mSomeFragment.callsomething();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement your method.. I've updated the question with the code I have. Apparently, I did not use fragmentTransaction to add the fragment to the manager.

Comment: It's not working. Error happened: "Can't change tag of fragment". Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Comment: use getSupportFragmentManager() if your app supporting v4.

Comment: Is it the only way? Why don't save the fragment instance in an attribute of the activity class?

Answer (score 9):

You have to do this :

```
frag.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(frag).commit();
frag.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(frag).commit();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Where should I put this? Is frag variable one of my fragments?

Answer (score 3):

Your fragments are managed by the adapter. Therefore, you also have to call for the adapter to refresh your fragments. These steps are necessary:

1. Override getItemPosition in your Adapter

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
       return POSITION_NONE;
   }
   ```
2. Once you did that call

   ```
   mViewPager.getAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   ```

   in your Activity. From the fragment object itself you could use a callback to inform the Activity of the need to refresh.

This will freshly populate the viewPager with new instances of your fragments which is like restarting / refreshing the fragment.

Hope it helps and this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();