# Android: Get Parent View's Framelayout from Fragment inside TabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

I have a `FragmentActivity` in which I am displaying two `Fragments`, `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`. In `Fragment A` I have another Fragment with Tabs. I have done this using classic `TabHost`. In this `TabHost` I have 2 more `Fragments` which has a `ListView`. Now what I want is on clicking on `listitem` I want to replace the content in `Fragment B` of parent `FragmentActivity`. Please help me to achieve this. I have tried the following till now.

```
1. View mContainer = (View)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rightpane);
2. ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup)getView().getParent();
3. Activity rrlist = ((RRPatientList)getParentFragment()).getActivity().getParent();
   View mContainer = (View) rrlist.findViewById(R.id.rightpane);

   ResultDetailView rdl = new ResultDetailView();
   rdl.setArguments(args);
   FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(mContainer.getId(), rdl);
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);     
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.commit();
```

Nothing is working and I am getting either `NullPointerException` or `No View Found for the ID ******` errors.

Please refer the screen shot for more info.

[image: Fragments]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**create method(like: updateFragment) in your activity to update fragment B. from fragment A's child fragment call that method(updateFragment) then that method(updateFragment) update fragment B.**

[here is answer for update fragment from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677266/1168654) - it 'll help you to update fragment B from your parent activity

[here is answer for call activity method from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659795/1168654) - it 'll help you to call parent activity method from fragment A's child fragment

Comment: But how to get ``FragmentActivity`` from ``ListFragment`` of ``TabHost``. Your code works when only there are two levels hierarchy (FragmentActivity -> Fragment), but I have FragmentActivity -> Fragment -> Fragment. How to achieve in this scenario?

Comment: same scenario work for n level of fragment because you are adding all fragment in one parent activity am i right?? then base is ACTIVITY. so you can call activity method from any fragment.