# Android: How to refresh online data when Internet is available without creating a new Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tv

When my `MainFragment` first loads, it checks for internet connectivity. If there is internet, it loads the content from online. However, if there is no internet connectivity, I replace the existing fragment `MainFragment` within the container `main_browse_fragment` with `InternetConnectivityFragment`.

Within `InternetConnectivtyFragment`, I have a Retry button that re-checks the internet, and if there is internet connectivity, I remove `InternetConnectivityFragment` and call `popbackstack`.

The problem is, when `popbackstack` is called, I dont know how to reload the online data from within `MainFragment`. The online data loading and internet check is done within `onActivityCreated` of `MainFragment.java`, but when `popbackstack` is called within `InternetConnectivityFragment.java`, the view of `MainFragment` is blank

Obviously this is because the fragment is not "created" and `onActivityCreated` is not called again, so no data is reloaded.

Here's the relevant code:

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends DetailsFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setupUIElements();

        if (isConnectingToInternet() == true)
        {
            // Call methods to load online data
        }
        else
        {
            InternetConnectivityFragment internetError = new InternetConnectivityFragment();

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_browse_fragment, internetError).commit();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

InternetConnectivityFragment.java:

```
public class InternetConnectivityFragment extends ErrorFragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "InternetFragment";
    private static final boolean TRANSLUCENT = true;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setErrorContent();
    }

    private void setErrorContent()
    {
        setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lb_ic_sad_cloud, null));
        setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_message));
        setDefaultBackground(TRANSLUCENT);

        setButtonText(getResources().getString(R.string.retry_connection));

        setButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                if (Singleton.getInstance().isConnectedToInternet()  == true)
                {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(InternetConnectivityFragment.this).commit();
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                    // How to call methods to re-load online data from MainFragment????
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried to perform the following within the `onClick` method:

```
MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(InternetConnectivityFragment.this).commit();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_browse_fragment, mainFragment).commit();
```

However, I believe this is wrong as it just adds a new fragment `MainFragment` on top of an already existing fragment.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Can you replace the fragment instead of just popping it?

Comment: I tried `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_browse_fragment, mainFragment).commit()` and commented out `popBackStack`, but that still means having to create a new `MainFragment`, which I'm sure is not the correct way.

Comment: I have been thinking of another approach to this: you can use just one fragment instead of two; now, when there is no content because of network, set visibility of a button and text to visible; when net is visible, set them to gone

Comment: I could use that approach, but then again, I'm using the `ErrorFragment` class, which has pretty much everything set up for me in terms of displaying the internet error content and button, which is why I'm using 2 fragments.

Comment: I found valid solutions in these SO posts - [Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager) and in [Android, How to restart/refresh a fragment from FragmentActivty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578000/android-how-to-restart-refresh-a-fragment-from-fragmentactivty) which you can look into. Hope that helps. Happy coding. :)